# windows phone 8 official supported file icons

Tags: file, types, icons

Does anyone know how to display the supported file type icons in WP8 ?
I have links on a xaml page which by clicking opens pdf, excel, word, powerpoints etc and these work nicely.
I would like to get the "official" icon which I can see for example in the office app in WP8 next to the link to indicate what kind of a file is in question.
I know from the file mimeType (for example application/pdf) what file is in question
Does anyone know how to accomplish this ?
Thanks,
Jani

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to get app product id, then use below code to get stream for official icon.

But you couldn't get icon of apps which are not scanned by InstallationManager.FindPackages().

```
IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package> apps = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackages();
foreach(var app in apps)
{
  if(app.Id.ProductId.Equals("APP_ID", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
  {
     var token = p.GetThumbnailToken();
     var name = app.Id.Name + SharedStorageAccessManager.GetSharedFileName(token);
     await SharedStorageAccessManager.CopySharedFileAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting, token);

     var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(name);                    
     var randomStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
     Stream stream = randomStream.AsStream();
  }
}
```